# Find most repeated words in large MySQL database

Tags: mysql

i have this table names `posts` with 
`id` and `content` where id its auto increment and content contain a `HTML` text so i need to get most repeated word in the content without get a html tags

what i try to use

```
SELECT word , COUNT(*) total FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT `id` , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`content`,' ',1),' ',-1) word FROM posts ) x GROUP BY word HAVING COUNT(*) > 3 ORDER BY total DESC , word
```

but its give me

```
word  | total
<div    100,000
```

only one result and its a html tags

so any good query for get most repeated word without html tags

and can i get most two word repeated word too like

youtube pattern ...

Comment: I cannot think of any other solution than having another HTML_TAGS table and comparing your result with that table.

Answer (score 0):

I'd loop through those HTML strings and extract the content using your html parser of choice and then you can either calculate the most common word in your application or insert the words back into mysql and then perform a simple query.

There is not an HTML parser in MySQL to my knowledge.

Good luck!